# Just how immune to paralysis is a creature that's immune to paralysis?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, immunities

Is there a distinction between **paralysis** and a **paralysis effect**? The *Monster Manual* Glossary on [paralysis](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#paralysis) says, "Unlike *hold person* and similar effects, a **paralysis effect** does not allow a new save each round" (313). Does this make monster paralysis effects different from a spell's paralysis effect and from *other kinds* of paralysis? And how far can immunity to paralysis be extended anyway?

- The type [dragon](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#dragon) includes among its traits immunity to paralysis effects (*MM* 308). Obviously, a dragon's immune to a [ghoul](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#ghoul)'s paralysis, but what if the dragon were [reduced to Dex 0](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#ability-damaged)? Would the dragon ignore the condition [paralyzed](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#paralyzed)? Does the dragon ignore the effects of the spell [*hold monster*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#hold-monster)?
- Creatures with the types [construct](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#construct) (*MM* 307), [elemental](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#elemental) (*MM* 308), and [ooze](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#ooze) (*MM* 313), and, for example, the [duergar](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDrtoDw.html#duergar-dwarf) (*MM* 92), the kuo-toa (*MM* 163-4), and the pseudodragon (*MM* 210-11) are immune to paralysis in general instead of being immune to paralysis *effects*. (I know, right?) Are such creatures immune to gaining the condition [paralyzed](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#paralyzed)? Does that include the paralysis for being reduced to Dex 0, too?

---

***Background:*** the Frostburn *spell* shivering touch *(104) deals a touched creature that has its SR overcome 3d6 points of Dexterity ability damage. Even the mightiest dragon usually has about Dex 10. Rather than equip all of the campaign's dragons with crazy countermeasures to this spell, I was kind of hoping for an easy out with the dragon's immunity to paralysis, but dragons have immunity to paralysis* effects. *The subtle difference between that and immunity to paralysis—if any—form this question's crux.*

Comment: See, I knew this'd get downvoted, but how else to ask about such a distinction when the game seems to make a distinction between *paralysis* and *paralysis effects*?

Comment: This is still a thing in 2020; see this Giant in the Playground thread [here](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?610884-Is-the-famous-dragon-slaying-shivering-touch-approach-to-dragon-slaying-worthless).

Answer (score 5):

To my understanding, reducing an ability score to 0 causes a condition that can't be avoided by natural resistances called "helpless".

All of this is mentioned in the basics section of the [Hypertext d20
srd](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm):

> #### [Ability Score Loss](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#abilityScoreLoss)
>
> Some attacks reduce the opponent’s score in one or more abilities.
>   This loss can be temporary (ability damage) or permanent (ability
>   drain).
>
> While any loss is debilitating, losing all points in an ability score
>   can be devastating.
>
> - Strength 0 means that the character cannot move at all. He lies helpless on the ground.
> - Dexterity 0 means that the character cannot move at all. He stands motionless, rigid, and helpless.
> - Constitution 0 means that the character is dead.
> - Intelligence 0 means that the character cannot think and is unconscious in a coma-like stupor, helpless.
> - Wisdom 0 means that the character is withdrawn into a deep sleep filled with nightmares, helpless.
> - Charisma 0 means that the character is withdrawn into a catatonic, coma-like stupor, helpless.

If you're immune to paralysis you can't be affected by things like ghoul touch, but things like hold person affect you (since hold person is a mind-affecting compulsion). Immunity to paralysis prevents you from being *physically* immobilized through spell effects.

The golems in your example are immune to hold person because it's a mind affecting effect and they have no intelligence score. The unicorn has an immunity to compulsion effects (which hold person falls under as well), which further distinguishes the difference between paralysis and hold.

Loss of ability score causes gain of helpless so even if you were immune to paralysis, you'd still be rendered immobilized when reduced to 0 dex regardless.

Comment: Both the *Player's Handbook* ("A character with
Dexterity 0 is paralyzed") (304) and the *Dungeon Master's Guide* ("A character with Dexterity 0 is paralyzed") equate Dexterity 0 with paralysis. I've always considered helplessness a consequence of that paralysis not *vice versa*.

Comment: All of the 0 ability score penalties aside from constitution(which causes death) result in helplessness. The only way to avoid this penalty is having a natural 0 or - in an ability score normally. This is one of the reasons why Ego Whip(Psion). Shivering Touch(Wizard) and Ray of Enfeeblement(Wizard) are good.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Isn't there a general rule that the Glossary's summaries are secondary to the actual rule? The actual rule in this case is DMG p. 289 (and PHB p. 134, which just directs the reader to the DMG), and matches the SRD.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but the *DMG* has that blurb about helplessness above only once (289), while the *DMG* and the *PH* both say twice, "A character with Dexterity 0 is paralyzed" (300 and 304, respectively). The *PH* doesn't even repeat the *DMG* section on Ability Score Loss. I can't help but think repeating the same thing four times overrides saying it once.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm pretty sure after text trumping tables, they're all just rules. However, it looks like the *RC* (*sigh*) addresses this, no longer equating Dex 0 with paralysis and, instead, with helplessness (6). Darn you, devs! Just write a clearer core book! `;-)`

Comment: The claim that a dragon's immunity to paralysis effects renders it immune to a ghoul's touch but not the spell *hold monster* is bold enough to require support beyond speculation. (And unicorns? Where?)

Comment: In order to be immune to hold person/monster, you'd have to be immune to mind effecting. It isn't paralysis caused by an attack, it's a compulsion that forces you to stop moving. Hold monster is *mind control*. Not paralysis.

Comment: @Sandwich Are you sure about [*hold person*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsHtoL.html#hold-person) not being paralysis?

Comment: Even if it is paralysis, there are two effects of hold person. The subject becomes paralyzed **and** freezes in place. If you have immunity to one you're still affected by the other.

Comment: So to end the effect of a *hold person* spell a creature would need to be subject to both a *remove paralysis* effect *and* sufficient heat to melt the bonds that have left the creature frozen in place? `;-)`

Comment: Well you'd just have to dispel it really. As you would any mental compulsion that prevents you from moving.