# Can an Oracle use Energy Body while paralyzed to end the paralysis?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions, immunities, oracle

One issue that came up in our last session is the use of Energy Body on a character that is already paralyzed. While paralysis prevents movement, it still allows for fully mental actions, which using Energy Body is. When using Energy Body, you are given the Elemental Subtype during the duration, which grants immunity to paralysis among its other effects.

If used while one of the applicable effects (such as bleeding or poisons, along with paralysis) are active, what happens? Would it suppress the effects, allowing the Oracle to regain their ability scores and move about freely until EB wears off?

Comment: The *cause* of the paralysis might be important here (cf. [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87776/8610)). Can that cause be added to the question?

Answer (score 3):

By the wording of the [Immunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Immunity-Ex-or-Su-) official term (emphasis added):

> A creature with immunities takes no damage from listed sources. Immunities can also apply to afflictions, conditions, spells (based on school, level, or save type), and other effects. A creature that is immune **does not suffer from these effects**, or any secondary effects that are triggered due to an immune effect.

It seems to me you would still 'be' paralyzed but you would not suffer the *effects* of the paralysis. In function, you'd regain control of your movement and not be helpless, etc., but when Energy Body wears off you might still be Paralyzed.

This is supported by other spells that specifically state their immunity:

[Protection from Evil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-evil)

> If successful, such effects are suppressed for the duration of this spell. The effects resume when the duration of this spell expires.

[Delay Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/delay-poison/)

> Any poison in its system or any poison to which it is exposed during the spell’s duration does not affect the subject until the spell’s duration has expired.